# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str iterando un json

Tags: python, json

Me da este error al intentar iterar un json :

```
counter.append(dato['monitorCounter'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Esta sería la parte de código donde ocurre el error:

```
 y = json.dumps(result_set) 
    counter=[]           
    for dato in y:
        counter.append(dato['monitorCounter'])
        print counter
```

El json es este, que es la variable y, que esta transformando en json result_set, basicamente con ese for y la lista counter, quiero coger los datos 'monitorCounter' y mostrarlos.

> [[["cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Backends,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Backend
> 0,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Backend
> 1,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Backend
> 2,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Backend
> 3,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Backend
> 4,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Backend
> 5,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Connections,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Connection 1016,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorConnectionRead": ["2"], "monitorConnectionGet": ["2"],
> "monitorConnectionOpsReceived": ["2"],
> "monitorConnectionOpsCompleted": ["1"], "monitorConnectionNumber":
> ["1016"], "monitorConnectionWrite": ["0"],
> "monitorConnectionOpsExecuting": ["1"], "monitorConnectionOpsPending":
> ["0"]}]], [["cn=Max File Descriptors,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorCounter": ["1024"]}]],
> [["cn=Total,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor", {"monitorCounter":
> ["1017"]}]], [["cn=Current,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorCounter": ["1"]}]], [["cn=Databases,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Frontend,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Database
> 0,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Database
> 1,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Database
> 2,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor", {"olmBDBEntryCache": ["0"],
> "olmBDBIDLCache": ["0"], "olmBDBDNCache": ["0"]}]],
> [["cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Listener
> 0,cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Listener
> 1,cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Listener
> 2,cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Log,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["50"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["49"]}]], [["cn=Bind,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorOpInitiated": ["17"], "monitorOpCompleted": ["17"]}]],
> [["cn=Unbind,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["16"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["16"]}]],
> [["cn=Search,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["17"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["16"]}]],
> [["cn=Compare,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["0"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["0"]}]],
> [["cn=Modify,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["0"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["0"]}]],
> [["cn=Modrdn,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["0"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["0"]}]], [["cn=Add,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorOpInitiated": ["0"], "monitorOpCompleted": ["0"]}]],
> [["cn=Delete,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["0"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["0"]}]],
> [["cn=Abandon,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated": ["0"],
> "monitorOpCompleted": ["0"]}]],
> [["cn=Extended,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor", {"monitorOpInitiated":
> ["0"], "monitorOpCompleted": ["0"]}]], [["cn=Overlays,cn=Monitor",
> {}]], [["cn=Overlay 0,cn=Overlays,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=SASL,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Bytes,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor", {"monitorCounter":
> ["55414"]}]], [["cn=PDU,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor", {"monitorCounter":
> ["928"]}]], [["cn=Entries,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorCounter": ["896"]}]],
> [["cn=Referrals,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor", {"monitorCounter":
> ["0"]}]], [["cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Max,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Max
> Pending,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Open,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Starting,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Active,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Pending,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Backload,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=State,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Runqueue,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Tasklist,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Time,cn=Monitor",
> {}]], [["cn=Start,cn=Time,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Current,cn=Time,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Uptime,cn=Time,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=TLS,cn=Monitor", {}]],
> [["cn=Waiters,cn=Monitor", {}]], [["cn=Read,cn=Waiters,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorCounter": ["1"]}]], [["cn=Write,cn=Waiters,cn=Monitor",
> {"monitorCounter": ["0"]}]]]

Como podría iterar ese json para coger solo los valores monitorCounter??

por ejemplo de esto :

[["cn=Write,cn=Waiters,cn=Monitor", {"monitorCounter": ["0"]}]]

Coger solo el 0

Answer (score 0):

El método `json.dump` devuelve un string. O sea, la variable `y` contiene una cadena de caracteres. Con el `for` lo que haces es recorrer la cadena caracter por caracter.

Dentro del ciclo `for`, la variable `dato` es de tipo string. Puedes acceder a cada uno de sus caracteres usando indices. Por ejemplo. `dato[0]` es el primer caracter en la cadena.

Las cadenas se indexan con enteros, y el error en el código es usar una string, lo que sería válido si `dato` fuera un diccionario.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
import json
result_set = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
y = json.dumps(result_set)
print("json.dumps ->", y)
for dato in y:
    print("dato->", dato)
```

produce:

```
json.dumps -> {"a": 1, "b": 2}
dato-> {
dato-> "
dato-> a
dato-> "
dato-> :
dato->  
dato-> 1
dato-> ,
dato->  
dato-> "
dato-> b
dato-> "
dato-> :
dato->  
dato-> 2
dato-> }
```

#### Solución

Bueno, no tienes un JSON en tu código para empezar. Lo que tienes es un diccionario que conviertes en un string JSON, que no te sirva para nada más que enviarlo a algún otro proceso.

Ya que tienes el diccionario, puedes recorrerlo directamente sin pasar por JSON, lo que ya ha sido documentado en tus otras preguntas sobre el mismo problema.